# Using constant memory with pandas xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, optimization, xlsxwriter

Im trying to use the below code to write large pandas dataframes to excel worsheets, if i write it directly the system is running out of RAM, is this a viable option or are there any alternatives?

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Python Output Analysis.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',options=dict(constant_memory=True))
```

Comment: For `constant_memory` to take effect you need to write row by row whereas I think pandas writes col by col (to be verified). So you might need to roll your own excel writing function with `iterrows()` (we be rather slow, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constant_memory` mode of XlsxWriter can be used to write very large Excel files with low, constant, memory usage. The catch is that the data needs to be written in row order and (as @Stef points out in the comments above) Pandas writes to Excel in column order. So `constant_memory` mode won't work with Pandas ExcelWriter.

As an alternative you could avoid ExcelWriter and write the data directly to XlsxWriter from the dataframe on a row by row basis. However, that will be slower from a Pandas point of view.

Comment: Yes ive tried this method and it was very slow to execute still unable to find a better alternative

Answer (score 0):

If your data is large, just consider saving the data with raw text file. e.g. csv, txt, etc.

```py
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, sep=',')
df.to_csv('file.tsv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

---

Or split DataFrame, and save to small files.

```py
df_size = df.shape[0]
chunksize = df_size//10
for i in range(0, df_size, chunksize):
    # print(i, i+chunksize)
    dfn = df.iloc[i:i+chunksize,:]
    dfn.to_excel('...')
```

Comment: xlsx is not an available format to store large data.

Comment: Problem is it has to be saved as an excel

Comment: Excel can maximum contain 1048576 rows

Comment: yeah the number of rows are usually never above 500k but when its copying data to output file its using up lot of ram was wondering if theres any way i can avoid that

Comment: How about split 10 files to save the df.

Comment: Im using an Excelwriter to write to multiple sheets so its still flooding the ram even if i divide it